# Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^4 + x^2 +1} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Evaluate the integral $\int \frac{x^2 + 1}{x^4 + x^2 +1} dx$

**The book hint is:**

Take $u = x- (1/x)$ but still I do not understand why this hint works, could anyone explain to me the intuition behind this hint?

**The book answer is:**

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take $x^2$ common out from numerator and denominator. Then your fraction becomes $$\frac{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^2}+1}$$ Now write $x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^2} = (x-\frac{1}{x})^{2}+2$

Comment: But I can see that the final answer in the book contains 2 arctan   ...... could you please explain this also for me?

Comment: Sure. After substitution, $t=x-\frac{1}{x}$, the integral becomes $\int \frac{1}{1+t^2} \ \, dt$ and integral of this is given by $\arctan(t)$

Comment: No I do not mean this

Comment: My answer is (1/3) \arctan (x^2 -1)/\sqrt {3} x  ..... but the book answer is

Comment: I will include it in the main question above

Comment: Is my answer correct? ...... I have included the answer of the book in the question .

Comment: @crskhr the integrand should be $\int \frac{1}{t^2+3}dt$ which becomes $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{t}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that we must compute the integral in the following way:
$$I=\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$I=\int\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)}\mathrm{d}x$$
After a fraction decomposition, 
$$I=\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+x+1}+\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2-x+1}$$
Now we focus on 
$$I_1=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+x+1}$$
Completing the square in the denominator produces 
$$I_1=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$
Then the substitution $u=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}(2x+1)$ gives 
$$I_1=\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+1}$$
$$I_1=\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
Similarly, 
$$I_2=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2-x+1}$$
$$I_2=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$
And the substitution $u=x-\frac12$ carries us to 
$$I_2=\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
Plugging in:
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\bigg(\arctan\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}+\arctan\frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigg)+C$$
Which is confusing, because nowhere did we use the suggested substitution. Furthermore, using the suggested substitution produces 
$$I=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2+3}$$
Which is easily shown to be 
$$I=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{x^2+1}{x\sqrt{3}}$$
[But apparently that is incorrect.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hojmgfvkqb) I am really unsure how this is the case. Try asking your teacher.

Comment: why you see that it is incorrect?

Comment: @hopefully Click this link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hojmgfvkqb

Comment: I have clicked it ...... I think the problem in your first solution because you decompose as if there were difference between 2 squares which is incorrect.

Comment: So I think the solution in the book is wrong.

Comment: @hopefully $$(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)=\\=x^2(x^2+x+1)-x(x^2+x+1)+(x^2+x+1)\\=x^4+x^3+x^2-x^3-x^2-x+x^2+x+1\\=x^4+x^2+1$$

Comment: @hopefully the book isn't wrong, but I don't know why $$3^{-1/2}\arctan\bigg((3^{1/2}x)^{-1}(x^2+1)\bigg)$$ is wrong